# does not echo full string

Tags: php

I have google coordinates that I have to change, but when I echo them, for example,

```
echo (string)28.9871692657471;
```

I get the result of

```
28.987169265747
```

" 1 " at the end disappears

```
echo (string) 28.9875984191895
```

" 5 " at the end disappears

I tried directly echoing it, without casting, but nothing has changed, the thing I want to do is to have this basic operation,

```
28.9875984191895 + 0.0000000000001 = 28.9875984191896
```

Is there something I am missing ? because I could not find anything about that when I search on the internet

Comment: Have you considered that perhaps you're running into PHP's floating point accuracy limits?

Comment: floating point numbers cannot represent all values. you might look to arbitrary precision systems like bcmath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
echo bcadd("28.9875984191895", "0.0000000000001", 13);
```

The last parameter is the number of decimals to display

Answer (score 4):

Floating point numbers are not accurate enough for that, but in any case the `php.ini` setting `precision` affects how many decimal digits are shown when a float is cast to a string, so try adjusting that (either edit the `php.ini` file, or use `ini_set("precision",50);`)

Comment: Note that this does not mean that `28.9871692657471` will be displayed as-is.

Comment: I should display them as-is

Answer (score 2):

Per the [PHP docs on floating point numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php):

> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher precision is necessary, the [arbitrary precision math functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) and [gmp](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) functions are available.